# Kibana discover tab shows 'searching' for a long time

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I am new to use kibana. Configured index and it shows all the fields. But when I click discover tab,the following screen is shown and the browser becomes unresponsive after sometime. Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reinstalling kibana and gave Time-field name along with index pattern. Thus solved the issue